# How to search for a CSS property of class using VS Code Regex

Tags: css, regex, visual-studio

I would like to create a Regex expression to be used as search query in VS Code, in order to do some overrides on an existing CSS files.

My scenario is close to this:

```
.myClass {
  font-size:10px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

What is the correct Regex to search all occurrences of .myClass containing the 'font-size:10px' property?

I.e I don't know what's needed in order to complete the regex expression here, and let VS Code search for the 'font-size:10px;' substring as well.

`/.myClass \{     \}/`

Comment: I'm not sure what I have to add on the regex below in order to extract the 'font-size:10px':

`/.myClass \{     \}`

Comment: Is `font-size:10px` always the first attribute? Then, something like `\.myClass\s*\{\s*font-size:10px;[\w\W]*?\}` might work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no 'font-size:10px' is not always the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\.myClass\s*\{[^{}\r]*font-size:10px;[^{}]*\}
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/wakqml/1/). The expression will match `.myClass {` and then any characters other than curly brackets up to `font-size:10px;`, then any text other than the same brackets till a close curly bracket.

EXPLANATION

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  myClass                  'myClass'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \{                       '{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^{}\r]*                 any character except: '{', '}', including linebreaks
                           (0 or more times matching the most amount possible)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  font-size:10px;          'font-size:10px;'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^{}]*                   any character except: '{', '}' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \}                       '}'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I was looking for!